# C++03: keep default copy constructor when using template constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++03

Imagine I create a class with a template constructor to define implementations later:

```
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    A(const T& arg);
};
```

How can I avoid overriding compiler's implicitly generated copy constructor `A(const A&)`? In C++11 I can do something like

```
#include <type_traits>
struct A {
    template<typename T, class = 
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<A, T>::value>::type>
    A(const T& arg);
};
```

and it works. But C++03 doesn't support default template arguments. Any workaround here?

Comment: The C++03 style is to [use a default function argument](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1d40c1197480ca8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. The compiler generated coppy constructor will kick in as needed. A copy constructor cannot be a template. For example,

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    template<typename T>
    A(const T& arg) { std::cout << "template\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(42);  // template ctor
    A b(a);   // copy ctor
    A c = b;  // copy ctor
}
```

Output:

> template

Comment: So it is impossible to replace a copy constructor with templates at all? Is that a special rule for copy constructors or a consequence of some more common rules?

Comment: @TigranSaluev Special rule for copy (and move) constructors, and for copy (and move) assignment operators.

Comment: @TigranSaluev Yes, it is impossible. I think the definition of what a copy constructor is states that it can't be a template. I'll find the rederence later.

Comment: That said, if the template constructor were instead `A(T& arg)`, then it would be used in place of the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need one. The constructor in question will instantiate to `A(const A&)` when given an `A`, which is the same as the actual copy constructor, so the non-template constructor will be preferred.